# Zeros of polynomials are continuous

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

For two sets $A,B$, let $d(A,B)=\sup_{x\in A}\inf_{y\in B}|x-y|+\sup_{y\in B}\inf_{x\in A}|x-y|$.

Let $p(z)=a_nz^n+\ldots+a_0$, and let $\epsilon>0$. Show that there exists $\delta>0$ such that for any $q(z)=b_nz^n+\ldots+b_0$ such that $\max_k|a_k-b_k|<\delta$, we have $d(Z_p,Z_q)<\epsilon$, where $Z_p,Z_q$ denote the sets of zeros of $p$ and $q$.

I think it must be somehow related to Rouche's theorem, but I can't see how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Write $q=p+(q-p)$ and choose $\delta$ small enough so that $|q-p|<|p|$ on the circles of radius $\epsilon$ centered at the roots of $p$.